# add new JTextField within an event handler

Tags: java, swing

i am trying to complete an assignment which is an inventory manager. it implements CRUD (create, retrieve, update and delete) functionality for three different categories - book, cd, dvd. i am trying to achieve this by using a JComboBox to allow the user to select which CRUD option they desire and then a JTextField in which they can enter the appropriate info. for the create option, i would like the user to enter the category and have a new JFrame open with a new JTextField where they can enter the author/artist/title.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUIProductView extends JFrame
{
    //private ProductController controller;
    //private Product model;

    private final JComboBox<String> dropDown; //drop down menu for multiple options
    private final JTextField textField1; //text field for create option
    private final JTextField textField2; //text field for retrieve option
    private final JTextField textField3; //text field for update option
    private final JTextField textField4; //text field for delete option

    private final JTextField bookField; //text field for new book entry
    private final JFrame newFrame; //new JFrame for when appropriate drop down option is selected

    private static final String[] dropDownText = 
        {"1. Create", "2. Retrieve", "3. Update", "4. Delete"}; //text for the JComboBox options

    public GUIProductView()
    {
        super("inventory manager");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        dropDown = new JComboBox<String>(dropDownText);
        dropDown.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        textField1 = new JTextField("Choose an option from drop down list");
        textField2 = new JTextField();
        textField3 = new JTextField();
        textField4 = new JTextField();

        add(dropDown);
        add(textField1);
        bookField = new JTextField();
        newFrame = new JFrame();

        TextFieldHandler handler = new TextFieldHandler();
        textField1.addActionListener(handler);

        dropDown.addItemListener(
                new ItemListener()
                {
                    //handler for JComboBox
                    @Override
                    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
                    {
                        JComboBox dropDown = (JComboBox) event.getSource();
                        Object selected = dropDown.getSelectedItem();

                        if(selected.toString().equals("1. Create"))
                        {
                            textField1.setText("Enter type of item to Create (book, cd or dvd");
                            textField1.setVisible(true);
                            textField2.setVisible(false);
                            textField3.setVisible(false);
                            textField4.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        else if(selected.toString().equals("2. Retrieve"))
                        {
                            textField2.setText("Enter item name to Retrieve");
                            add(textField2);
                            textField2.setVisible(true);
                            textField1.setVisible(false);
                            textField3.setVisible(false);
                            textField4.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        else if(selected.toString().equals("3. Update"))
                        {
                            textField3.setText("Enter item name to Update");
                            add(textField3);
                            textField3.setVisible(true);
                            textField1.setVisible(false);
                            textField2.setVisible(false);
                            textField4.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            textField4.setText("Enter item name to Delete");
                            add(textField4);
                            textField4.setVisible(true);
                            textField1.setVisible(false);
                            textField2.setVisible(false);
                            textField3.setVisible(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        String string = "";
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getSource() == textField1)
            {
                //create text field
                //open new JFrame with text field for user to enter appropriate info
                //creating three text fields where the user can choose 
                newFrame.setSize(250, 100);
                newFrame.setVisible(true);

                string = event.getActionCommand(); //variable to store the user input

                //JTextField bookField = new JTextField();
                if (string.equals("book"))
                {
                    add(bookField);
                    bookField.setVisible(true);
                    bookField.setText("enter author and title");
                }
                if (string.equals("cd"))
                {
                    JTextField cdField = new JTextField(); //text field for new cd entry
                    add(cdField);
                    cdField.setVisible(true);
                    cdField.setText("enter artist and album");
                }
                if (string.equals("dvd"))
                {
                    JTextField dvdField = new JTextField(); //text field for new dvd entry
                    add(dvdField);
                    dvdField.setVisible(true);  
                    dvdField.setText("enter title");
                }
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == textField2)
            {
                //retrieve text field
                //maybe use JOptionPane to display search result?
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == textField3)
            {
                //update text field
                //new window with text field for new update info
            }
            else
            {
                //delete text field
                //JOptionPane to show confirm message
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Product model = new Product();
        //ProductController controller = new ProductController(model);

        GUIProductView view = new GUIProductView();
        view.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        view.setSize(350, 100);
        view.setVisible(true);

        //model.setView(view);

        //view.setModel(model);

        //view.start();
    }
}
```

i think i need for there to be 4 separate text fields because i need them to function differently. i tried to add the text fields in the event listeners, but they do not show. if i add them outside of the event handler, then it works, but it gives me 4 separate text fields when it is first run. i want it to look cleaner than that when first opened. also, when the new JFrame opens after input is received from the text field, it opens without the new text field in that JFrame. so, is it possible to add a new text field within an event handler? if so, please tell me how!!

Comment: Did you try calling `revalidate()` after you added the text fields before? You have to let the window know it needs to update it's layout.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to do all this swapping of visibility of components and such? It looks awfully convoluted and looks like you're doing something in a very complex way that instead can be done much easier say with a CardLayout or different program structure.

Comment: i have been reading through things here and CardLayout has come up quite a few times, but that is not something we have learned in the course, so i have been avoiding it. perhaps i should stop avoiding it...

Comment: @NicholasEason i tried that after your suggestion, but there was no change. still no text field is populated.

Comment: Wouldn't a `JDialog` suit you better than a `JFrame`?

Comment: @NicholasEason is in fact correct. I would call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` at the very end of your `itemStateChanged(...)` method immediately after the last `else` block (**not** inside of the else block).